# Is it insecure or bad practice to store a client certificate as an embedded resource in a web service?

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

I am designing a web API service in C# that connects to a third party to retrieve its information.  The third party requires a client certificate for mutual authentication.  The code works fine with the certificate installed on my development machine.

In the course of writing this, I realized using the X509Certificate2 class, I can actually load the certificate from a byte array, after loading it from an embedded resource in one of the API's support DLLs.  My first thought was that if I did so, it would make deployment and future expansion easier, as the servers where this will be hosted wouldn't have to have the client certificates installed on them (it will be hosted on several different servers, and more in the future).

My concern is, that I would be doing something insecure or bad practice, especially since it also means storing the password with it (or in a database, or whatever), as compared to just installing the certificate on the server.

So my question is, should I avoid doing this?  My instinct says I should avoid it, but it would make things easier later.

I am not well versed in certificates, and my research online looking for opinions has led to several discussions of HOW to do it, but I already know that.  None of them seem to address whether you *should* do it.

Comment: bad idea for many reasons. Somebody can steal the cert from your binary. What happens when the cert expires?

Comment: Well that's the part I don't know.  If they have access to the server, and the dll, I would assume they have access to the cert installed on the server as well.  Good point about expiration, but we deploy this service relatively often, so that wouldn't be a huge concern.